# Missing auth-header when trying to pass in Auth token as an ENV variable

Tags: bash, gitlab

I'm writing a CI-pipeline in Gitlab that calls a bash script.

I'm having an issue with my script when I try to pass in an AUTH header into my curl request when it is coming from an ENV variable that is set outside of the script itself (inside Gitlabs ci/cd variables).

Currently trying to make the below curl request:

```
echo $AUTH_TOKEN
OUTPUT=`curl $URL -H "$AUTH_TOKEN"`
echo $OUTPUT
```

Result:

'Authorization: basic secretpass'

**Error received:** Error: "message":"Missing authorization header."

**Gitlab CI/CD Variables:**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| URL | example.com/api/v1/example |
| AUTH_TOKEN | 'Authorization: basic secretpass' |

If I update my bash script to include the ENV variable inside, then the script is successful.

```
AUTH_TOKEN='Authorization: basic secretpass'
echo $AUTH_TOKEN
OUTPUT=`curl $URL -H "$AUTH_TOKEN"`
echo $OUTPUT
```

Result:

```
'Authorization: basic secretpass'

{
  "items": [
    {
      "example": "my expected response"
    }
  ],
  "test": "example"
}
```

Any ideas..?

Comment: I think that this has to do with the fact the when it comes from your env variable from gitlab, the string comes with single quotes, and maybe this is causing some sort of parse problem, when you put it inside your script you're a not including the quotes on the string